# React-Redux-Firebase new hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I have set up redux and react and they are working well. I wanted now to sync data from firestore directly into redux state using the hook useFirestoreConnect and useFirestore().

This code works:

```
function BannerG() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    // const banneAG = useSelector(state => state.banneAG)

    const firestore = useFirestore();
    useFirestoreConnect( props => [{collection : "layoutElements", doc: 'BannerG'}])
    const aa = useSelector(state  => state.firestore.data.layoutElements)
    console.log(aa)
```

In the console is printed the object with {BannerG: {H1: blah, H2:Blah blah, …………}}

but if I instead use

```
function BannerG() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    // const banneAG = useSelector(state => state.banneAG)

    const firestore = useFirestore();
    useFirestoreConnect( props => [{collection : "layoutElements", doc: 'BannerG'}])
    const aa = useSelector(state  => state.firestore.data.layoutElements.BannerG)
    console.log(aa)
```

when I run, returns an error saying that BannerG is undefined. If I try to use later one, aa.BannerG.H1 gives as well error

Anyone has an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't found it directly in any reference, but only in examples. 
[image]

It seems useSelector needs square brackets like:

```
const aa = useSelector(state  => state.firestore.data.layoutElements['BannerG'])
```

I found it like this in examples [github react-redux-firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/master/docs/api/useFirestoreConnect.md), [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) and on [react-redux-firebase.com reference](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore).

Unfortunately I cannot test it anyhow at the moment, so please let me know if it works or not.